# Codeigniter adding anchor_class in pagination to the specified element

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

this is my first time with CI pagination and I can't find info how to add `anchor_class` to specified link. For example my last item in pagination, which called "NEXT" have `class="last"` but I don't know how to add `class="last"` only to this element. This is what I tried:

```
$config['base_url']   = site_url('page');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->news_job->countAllMods();

    $config['per_page']   = '1';
    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['last_link']  = FALSE;
    $config['uri_segment'] = '2'; 

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['next_link']  = 'Next';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="button_pagination_nav button_graydark_nav"><a>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>&nbsp;';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="button_pagination_nav button_graylight_nav">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>&nbsp;';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="button_pagination_nav button_graydark_nav">';
    $config['anchor_class'] = 'class="last" ';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = 'Back';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

so as You can see I'm using `$config['anchor_class']` but with that all my pagination links gets `class="last"`. So what should I do, to add `class="last"` only to next_tag_close?

Comment: Hey, I notice that somebody else posted an answer and that you were a bit rude to him because he didn't _get_ your solution. I understand that can be upsetting, but could you post a clearer description of what you would like to do, as well as perhaps an example?

Comment: thanks for understanding, but i said few times what I want, but he still added his opinion. I dont know what can be more clearly. I need to add `class="last"` to my pagination button, which is created with the tool `$config['next_tag_open']` and `$config['next_tag_close']`. I need to add `class="last"` to his child element, which is ANCHOR. Becouse now my all anchors have `<a class="last"...>` but I need it only here `<li class="button_pagination_nav button_graydark_nav"><a href="" class="last"></a></li>`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but in codeigniter 3 this one works

> $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'last');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="last_link">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$(function(){
    $(".last_link a").addClass('last');
});
```

Comment out this line:

```
$config['anchor_class'] = 'class="last" ';
$config['last_link']  = TRUE;
```

Here is some [Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

Comment: you are not helping me, I need to add `class="last"` into anchor tag

Comment: Showed you a reference friend. Edited my answer as per your requirement. Have you seen the reference?

Comment: sir, don't be manace, but look what i've asked. I don't need to add `class="last"` to my LI element, I need to add it to specified ANCHOR element, which finds in my LI element. Now clear?

Comment: And one more thing.... you did same what I did in my code, just changed arrays element name....

Comment: Did I? Did I just changed the array element names on my own will? Would suggest you to read the docs carefully once again.